# как перевести yii2 на production

Tags: php, yii2

Я облазил весь интернет в поиске того, как перевести yii2 на продакшин. И практическе везде я видел ответы типа:

Нужно сменить в web/index.php на

```
 defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);
 defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'prod');
```

У меня возник вопрос,что правильно ли это?
Из моего опыта, я подумал что это как то не правильно. 
Работая 2года с magento2, для перевода использовалось что то типо

```
bin/magento deploy -f :mode:set mode
```

Возможно что то такого есть и в yii2
Можете подсказать, как правильно перевести на продакшин. 
Если всетаки ответ с заменой в файле web/index.php является правильным, прошу прощение.

Спасибо

Comment: Выполните команду **php init** для продакшен окружения в корне проекта и выберите **production environment**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это правильно. `index.php` должен быть у вас в `.gitignore` и у каждого разработчика он может быть свой, соответственно и в зависимости от окружения он будет различаться.

В шаблоне [yii2-app-advanced](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced) на GitHub вы можете увидеть, что в папке `environments` имеются свои файлы `index.php` для dev-окружения и prod-окружения.

Если у вас в корне есть файл `init` то вы можете разворачивать приложение с помощью консольной команды:

```bsh
php init
```

и выбирать окружение `dev` или `prod`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!